# Estimate quantile contours from probability density function

Tags: machine-learning, density-function, density-estimation

Presume we have some function $P(X)$ that is either a valid or un-normalized probability density function.  Here $X$ is high dimensional.  I'd like to get insight about the ***relative*** density via quantile contours, or something related to quantiles of the density throughout the support.  As just a simple example to help describe it....I've overlaid a plot below....although this is kernel density estimates don't make any assumptions on $P(X)$ except that it's smooth/continuous.  Note that I don't want it for plotting -- i want it for online anomaly detection, but without information on the ***relative*** density i can't do any kind of inference on the fly from a PDF.

Explanation of below plot:

The contour lines are quantile contours in 5% intervals. This means that about 5% of the points generated from the estimated nonparametric distribution are below the lowest contour, 10% are below the next contour, and so on. The highest contour has about 95% of the points below it.

[image: quantileContours]

Comment: what do you know about P(X)? do you know it's form? is derivable/continuous? or it's just an oracle function?

Comment: The function, and it's first derivative, are continuous (most likely it's of a neural network form).